# Only allow specific transfers in solana

Tags: solana

I want only specific public keys/accounts (decided by votes) to be able to transfer SOL into a project account. Just anyone should not be able to transfer SOL into the project account.
The project account in question is going to be created using my solana program.

Could someone here please inform if this is TECHNICALLY FEASIBLE or not and how to go about it conceptually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fundamentally:**

1. A wallet owner can use system transfer of SOL from any ***system owned account*** to ***any account*** (either system owned or program owned).
2. Programs can transfer SOL from ***any program owned account*** to ***any account*** (either system owned or program owned).

What you're looking for is not feasible. For example in option 1 you'd have to be in the system transfer logic to prevent transfers and for option 2 it still won't prevent what can be done by option 1.

Comment: C Thanks for replying. Is there no option to filter or some kind of event/callback that my on chain code can connect to? Etherium has something similar https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41659/how-can-i-decline-a-smart-contract-transaction.

Comment: If you thought my answer addressed your question, please accept it. You should probably create a new question with your comment here that made.